ROS2, Create3, Node subscribes to topic /tf but cannot receive data
In ROS2 for the iRobot Create3.
I created a node and subscribed to the topics /tf and tf_static. It seems to work because I can compile it and subscribed to other topics without any problems. But /tf and tf_static doesn't seem to send anything back. At least I can't print the information. I can see both nodes in rqt, so they are there.

"ros2 topic echo /tf"
Cannot echo topic 'namespace/tf', as it contains more than one type:
[geometry_msgs/msg/TransformStamped, tf2_msgs/msg/TFMessage]


ros2 topic info namespace/tf
Publisher count: 1
Subscription Count: 0

When I subscribe Subscription Count is 1, that works.
Here is my code:
TF_Subscriber::TF_Subscriber(const Create3_Config* config, const std::string& node_name)
    : Node(node_name), create3_config(config)
{
    // /tf[tf2_msgs / msg / TFMessage]
    tf_subscription_call = this->create_subscription<geometry_msgs::msg::TransformStamped>(
        (std::string(create3_config->ros_namespace) + "/tf").c_str(),
        rclcpp::SensorDataQoS(), std::bind(&TF_Subscriber::tfCallback, this, std::placeholders::_1));

    // /tf_static[tf2_msgs / msg / TFMessage]
    tf_static_subscription_call = this->create_subscription<geometry_msgs::msg::TransformStamped>(
        (std::string(create3_config->ros_namespace) + "/tf_static").c_str(),
        rclcpp::SensorDataQoS(), std::bind(&TF_Subscriber::tf_staticCallback, this, std::placeholders::_1));
}

void TF_Subscriber::tfCallback(const geometry_msgs::msg::TransformStamped::SharedPtr tf_msg)
{
    auto timestamp = tf_msg->header.stamp;

    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "TF Timestamp: %f",
        timestamp.sec + timestamp.nanosec * 1e-9
    );

    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "transform,roatation: X:%f, Y:%f, Z:%f, W:%f",
        tf_msg->transform.rotation.x,
        tf_msg->transform.rotation.y,
        tf_msg->transform.rotation.z,
        tf_msg->transform.rotation.w
    );
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "transform,translation: X:%f, Y:%f, Z:%f",
        tf_msg->transform.translation.x,
        tf_msg->transform.translation.y,
        tf_msg->transform.translation.z
    );
}

void TF_Subscriber::tf_staticCallback(const geometry_msgs::msg::TransformStamped::SharedPtr tf_static_msg)
{
    auto timestamp = tf_static_msg->header.stamp;

    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "TF Timestamp: %f",
        timestamp.sec + timestamp.nanosec * 1e-9
    );

    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "transform,roatation: X:%f, Y:%f, Z:%f, W:%f",
        tf_static_msg->transform.rotation.x,
        tf_static_msg->transform.rotation.y,
        tf_static_msg->transform.rotation.z,
        tf_static_msg->transform.rotation.w
    );
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "transform,translation: X:%f, Y:%f, Z:%f",
        tf_static_msg->transform.translation.x,
        tf_static_msg->transform.translation.y,
        tf_static_msg->transform.translation.z
    );
}

The only thing I can think of is the variable names are wrong, but I assume that would give me a compiler error. I am also sure the node is spinning. At least it is called and other nodes spin.
Any ideas?

Have you confirmed that there are messages being published on the topic? What does ros2 topic info and hz say about it?

I edited my post and added more info. I guess it is the message type, but I am not sure how to change it in the code.

You are subscribing to the topic with a mismatched type you won't receive any data.
You should subscribe with tf2_msgs/msg/TFMessage not a geometry_msgs/msg/TransformStamped
That will get you the data. But after that you likely didn't want that subscription anyway you should use the tf2 libraries to access the data.
There's an intro tutorial here
https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Tutorials/Intermediate/Tf2/Introduction-To-Tf2.html

Thanks that was my mistake.
I will read the tutorial.
Is it correct that /tf_static will be published only once? And when? Because I subscribe to /tf and /tf_static  but only /tf sends me data back.

Please accept this answer as it answers the question. Please ask any follow up questions as new questions instead of asking a question in a comment.
